# How can I see what is stored at location 0xaddress(%register)?

Tags: assembly, gdb, machine-code

I'm looking at the instruction `cmp 0x204d63(%rip),%eax` in x86 machine assembly. I am using the gdb debugger.

I know that the bit `0x204d63(%rip)` is technically adding `(%rip)+0x204d63`. I believe that this is adding the address to `%rip` to the address `0x204d63` to refer to a new address, is this correct?

How can I use the gdb debugger to see what is kept at this address?

Answer (score 0):

GDB should show you the effective address in a comment, like this:

```
0x0000000000421dc3 <main+5091>: lea    0xa827e(%rip),%rsi        # 0x4ca048
```

You can cast that to a suitable type (perhaps `unsigned long *`) and print that:

```
(gdb) print *(unsigned long)0x4ca048
$1 = 540701477
```